# Parameterizing an array for IN / =ANY clauses on PHP with PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, parameterized-query

I need to pass an array of strings in a parameterized query. I tried the following but it doesn't work at all.

```
$params = array( array('bob','andrew','larry') );
pg_query_params($conn, 'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field = ANY($1)', $params)
```

I've seen solutions that converts the array to a string and then uses string_to_array to convert the input to an array on the database side, but as those strings are input from users this could end badly, even if I used a delimiter other than a comma. I'd rather use a cleaner solution for this, if possible.

Is there a way to keep this query parameterized and pass an array to it, without resorting to converting the data to a string?

By the way, I'm using PostgreSQL 8.3

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP PDO: Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pgsql.so` is linked to `libpq` which does not have this capability.

Internally, it would need to serialize an array into string anyway.

`libpqtypes` has this capability built in, but I'm now aware of any `PHP` libraries using it.